# ChromeDriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

умельцы. Возникла следующая проблема:

1) Просмотрев видео и следовав всем инструкциям в нем (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXfajSjAFQw&feature=youtu.be), при запуске кода возникает данная ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Моя компетенция позволяет только установить, что проблема в самом chromedriver'e, но что именно настроено не так понять не могу. 
введите сюда описание изображения

3) При запуске кода должна произойти выгрузка с сайта со значениями. Как поправить данную проблему ?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import smtplib


class Coronavirus():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/C/Users/Saint/Desktop/chromedriver")

    def get_data(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
        table = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_table_countries_yesterday"]/tbody[1]')
        country_element = table.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'USA')]")
        row= country_element.find_element_by_xpath(",/..")

        data = row.text.split(" ")
        total_cases = data[1]
        new_cases = data [2]
        total_deaths = data [3]
        new_deaths = data [4]
        active_cases = data [5]
        total_recovered = data [6]
        serious_critical = data [7]

        print("Country: " + country_element.text)
        print("Total cases:" + total_cases)
        print("New cases:" + new_cases)
        print("Total deaths:" + total_deaths)
        print("New deaths:" + new_deaths)
        print("Active cases:" + active_cases)
        print("Total recovered:" + total_recovered)
        print("Serious, critical cases:" + serious_critical)


        self.driver.close()



def send_mail(country_element, total_cases, new_cases, total_death, new_death, total_recovered, active_cases):

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.echo()
    server.starttls()
    server.echo()

    server.login('gawrilenkomaxim@gmail.com')

    subject = 'Coronavirus stats in' + country_element +'!'

    body = 'Today in ' + country_element +'\
            \nThere is new data on coronavirus:\
            \nTotal cases: ' + total_cases + '\
            \nNew cases:' + new_cases + '\
            \nTotal deaths' + total_death + '\
            \nNew deaths: ' + new_death + '\
            \nActive cases ' + active_cases + '\
            \nTotal recovered ' + total_recovered + '\
            \nCheck the link: http://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail('gawrilenkomaxim@gmail.com', msg)
    print("сообщение отправлено")

    server.quit()


bot = Coronavirus()
bot.get_data()
```

Comment: Предлагаю начать с вдумчивого чтения ошибок, а не паниковать сразу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>вдумчиво прочитайте полдня-день, переберите массу вариантов ответов, **для всех операционок**, для всех версии пакетов, устаревших гипотез в рунете. Проявите недюжинную смекалку над мутабельностью пакетов и их совместимостью. Заодно обновите Виндовс, купите ноутбук помошнее</del>

Скопируйте chromedriver.exe в папку со скриптом или куда в каталог Python. Или заведите за правило уазывать в скрипте executable_path

```
self.driver =   webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("C:\User\Program Files\chrome-driver\chromedriver.exe"))
```

Берегите себя и свое время от "умельцев", не указывайте свой E-Mail и пароль от почтового ящика в вопросе, в скрипте вопроса